# Find the coefficient of $x^{15}y^4$ in the expansion of $(2x – 3y)^{19}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

Not even sure I understand this question or know where to start, I understand the basics of finding coefficients but don't get how it's calculated "in the expansion of" another number. Looking for some sort of explanation as to how to solve this. I understand solving binomial coefficients but I'm not entirely sure how they related in this type of question.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that by the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement)
$$\begin{align}(2x – 3y)^{19}=(2x + (-3y))^{19}&=\sum_{k=0}^{19}\binom{19}{ k}(2x)^k(– 3y)^{19-k}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{19}\left[\binom{19}k(2)^k(-3)^{19-k}\right]x^ky^{19-k}\end{align}$$
Therefore the expansion of the $19$th-power of the binomial $2x – 3y$ is a sum of terms of the form $c_kx^ky^{19-k}$.
Finding the coefficient of $x^ky^{19-k}$ means that we have to find the coefficient $c_k$.

So what it is the coefficient $c_{15}$ of $x^{15}y^4$?

Comment: Wait where did the 15 come from? Where is that being defined?

Comment: @Lakeland $c_k$ is the coefficient $x^{k}y^{19-k}$. $k=15$ is what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the binomial theorem? What does it say about $(2x-3y)^{19}$? That expanded form is what they mean by "the expansion". Once you have that expansion, somewhere in there there is a term with $x^{15}y^4$, and that term has a coefficient. You're being asked what that coefficient is.

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain the coefficient it is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{15}y^4]}\color{blue}{(2x-3y)^{19}}
> &=[x^{15}y^4]\sum_{j=0}^{19}\binom{19}{j}(2x)^j(-3y)^{19-j}\tag{1}\\
> &=[y^4]\binom{19}{15}2^{15}(-3y)^{4}\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{19}{4}2^{15}\cdot 3^4\tag{3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=102\,877\,110\,208}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement)*.
- In (2) we select the coefficient of $x^{15}$.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $y^4$.

Comment: @Lakeland: Let's see ... Maybe you want to add your steps in the follow-up question.

Comment: Could you please expand upon 3, and how it's calculated to the solution? Still not quite sure I understand the logic behind it. 19!/4! = 121645100408832000/24 = 5068545850368000, then 19!/4! * 2^15 * 3^4? I don't get the same answer as you so I'm clearly doing something wrongly.

Comment: @Lakelend: Recall $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, so $\binom{19}{4}=\frac{19!}{4!15!}$.